# Making a C socket Program to work online on WAN

Tags: c, sockets

How can a C socket program be made to communicate online on a Wide Area Network (WAN)? For example, having a server program (in C socket) running on a friend's computer in UK that could be accessed on a computer running a client program(in C socket) located in Russia. I tried my client/server online but it did not work. It only worked on my local machine.

Comment: we need more details - for example: what kind of connection to the internet do you and your friend have?  And if it is a separate box from your computer have you and your fiend done the port forwarding?  And what kind of firewall do you have running on your and your friend's computers?

Comment: Maybe try a third party client server app that you know works - like an FTP, telnet or SSH client server program.  There are lots of those so when you get one of them working you know it isn't the configuration of the connection.

Comment: These days most PCs run behind NATing routers. You will need to configure your router to allow connections to come through. Note, if you openthe first server you write to wide wild internet, it probably will be hacked and your computer will be pwned.

Comment: @n.m. It won't "probably" be hacked, there's a very small chance it will be hacked. Most scanners try to exploit common vulnerabilities, they aren't going to know about the server you just wrote or how to hack it, and they aren't going to bother finding out unless you have lots of people running your server. (Realistically, the worst consequence would be that a port scanner connects to your server and crashes it because of a bug in the server. And that's still not very likely)

Answer (score 0):

A connection between two computers looks very similar to a phone call, but actually there are lots of details that may turn it into a difficult thing.

Unfortunately, you haven't provided these details. So, let me ask them to you:

1. Are you connected directly to a telco, using 3G, for instance ? Or are you connected to another device that is connected to the Internet ? For instance, a 3G modem, that offers Wi-Fi connectivity ?
2. The same questions should be answered by your friend.

These two questions will provide a 1st step to understand and solve your problem.

Good luck, and a fine week for you and family.